# Async Pipe difference between as and let

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Take these examples :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="vo$ | async; let vo">
```

and

```
<ng-container *ngIf="vo$ | async as vo">
```

They have the same purpose, getting the latest value of the observable into the variable `vo`.

But is there any difference between these 2 syntax ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is probably more towards how Structural Directive works rather than the Async Pipe. `as` and `let` syntax are part of Angular Template syntax that Structural Directive makes use of.

There is no difference from the Angular Template syntax side of things. They are valid syntax of Angular template.

However, they're different in how they would be strongly typed. Take a look at  the following code of `ng_if.ts` from Angular source

```js
/**
 * @publicApi
 */
export class NgIfContext<T = unknown> {
  public $implicit: T = null!;
  public ngIf: T = null!;
}
```

The Structural Directive author can help the consumers in providing a strongly-typed Context. Since there are `as` and `let`, the Context also needs to account for both

- `$implicit` allows `let` to be type-safe
- `ngIf` (or the Directive's selector) allows `as` to be type-safe

Further explanation: `$implicit` is a special property that allows a consumer of a `ng-template` to grab the context's implicit data by `let someVar`

```html
<ng-template let-implicit let-someNamedVar="someNamedVar"></ng-template>
```

In the case of `*ngIf`, we can rewrite the `<ng-container *ngIf` in its long form so we can see how the `NgIfContext` makes sense

```html
<!-- <ng-container *ngIf="vo$ | async as vo"></ng-container> -->
<ng-template [ngIf]="vo$ | async" let-vo="ngIf">
   <ng-container></ng-container>
</ng-template>

<!-- <ng-container *ngIf="vo$ | async;let vo"></ng-container> -->
<ng-template [ngIf]="vo$ | async" let-vo>
   <ng-container></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```