# Difference between "let" and "as" in an angular directive

Tags: angular

Given these two calls to "ngIf" in an angular template:

```html
  <div *ngIf="myValue$ | async; let myValue">
    My Value is: {{myValue}}
  </div>
  <br>
  <div *ngIf="myValue$ | async as myValue">
    My Value is: {{myValue}}
  </div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ij131f?file=src/main.ts

Functionally, both versions seem to be returning the same result. What is the difference between `let` and `as` in these templates? Is this difference relevant when implementing other template types(ie. something other than ng-if)?

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71617867/async-pipe-difference-between-as-and-let ?